# Barcode generate doesn't work?

Tags: c#

I generate  barcode but it is not active with scanner. I am using C# + SQL server 2102 and using font "@IDAHC39M Code 39 Barcode"

I using this code.

```
   private void btngeneratebarcode_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string id;
        Random barcode = new Random();
        int i = barcode.Next();
        id = i.ToString();
        int k = int.Parse(id);
        int x = k + 1;
        string y = "0" + x + "0";
        lbbarcode.Text = y.ToString();
        lbbarcode.Visible = true;
        textBox1.Text = x.ToString();
    }
```

I display the barcode to a label and then print the label bar for product code, but while I scan with barcode scanner it is no active, no any result.

It is my first barcode generate. I don''t know that this is the right method.

Thnaks in advance.

Comment: Why do you cast `i` to a string and then parse it back to an integer?

Comment: Why `int i = barcode.Next(); id = i.ToString(); int k = int.Parse(id);` instead of just `k = barcode.Next();`? Especially the conversion to a string just to parse it in the next step is funny.

Comment: SQL Server 2102?  Dang son, give me a copy pls.

Comment: I get no idea with generating barcode. I learn from google with many way but I just follow them. I don't know it at all.  Please share any source code.

Answer (score 0):

Barcodes have specific rules to create them. You are using Code 39 for what I see, so you must add the start/stop char at the first and last position.

Usually the start/stop char is represented by the start (`*`), so if your font accomplishes that you can modify your code with this:

```
string y = "*0" + x + "0*";
```

Else you must change the star to the char used as start/stop by your font.